# Reflecting vectors in Manhattan Space (Unit Cube)

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Given two vectors $A$ and $B$ on the unit cube, I am trying to get the flipped vector $C$, also on the unit cube, that lies on the opposite side of $B$ from $A$

The following are the conditions of the "reflected" operator:

- assume that B's components are either 0, 1, or -1. aka B is either a corner vector or a center-face/center-edge vector
- we are dealing with MANHATTAN space. operators such as dot and cross don't have the same result in this space, so I don't recommend using them.
- distance(v1-v2) = distance(v2-v3) = 2 * distance(v1-reflected(v1,v2))   <- aka maintain manhattan distances
- cmax(abs(v3)) == cmax(abs(v1))
- reflected(v1,v2) == reflected(reflected(v1,v2), v2) //the reflection of a reflection is the original vector
- reflected(v1,v2) only has 1 solution, for all v1,v2
- the function maps for every vector in the unit square (aka continuous)
- reflected(v1,v2) = reflected(v1,-v2)
- reflected(v1,v1) = reflected(-v1,v1) = v1

The following are a few examples of inputs v1 and v2, and the reflection v3:

- v1=(1,0), v2=(1,1), reflected(v1,v2)=(0,1).
- v1=(1,y), v2=(1,0), reflected(v1,v2)=(1,-y)
- v1=(x, 1), v2=(0,1), reflected(v1,v2)=(-x,1)
- v1=(x,y), v2=(1,1), reflected(v1,v2) = (y,x) (remember that this only applies for cmax(abs(v1))==1)
- v1=(x,y), v2=(-1,1), reflected(v1,v2) = (-y, -x)
- v1=(1,y), v2=(0,1), reflected(v1,v2) = (-1, y)
- v1=(x,1), v2=(1,0), reflected(v1,v2) = (x, -1)

The 3D case changes things slightly.  In a nutshell, we want the reflection to be on the same plane as v1 and v2, during this operation. In other words:

- v1=(0,0,1), v2=(1,1,1), reflected(v1,v2)=(1,1,0)
- v1=(0.1,0.5,1), v2=(0,0,1), reflected(v1,v2)=(-0.1,-0.5,1)

I have it working in 2D, but need it in 3D.
Here is a working script for the 2D case (with all vectors on the unit square):

```
public Vector2 Reflected_2general(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
    {
        //Looks like it works, make sure to test it!!

        // Translate the coordinates by subtracting v2 from v1
        Vector2 v1_t = new Vector2(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y);

        // Perform a 45-degree rotation (either clockwise or counterclockwise)
        // This is equivalent to swapping the x and y coordinates
        Vector2 v1_r = new Vector2(v1_t.y, v1_t.x);

        // Reflect across the x-axis
        // This is equivalent to negating the y coordinate
        Vector2 v1_rf = new Vector2(v1_r.x, -v1_r.y);

        // Translate the coordinates back by adding v2
        Vector2 v3 = new Vector2(v1_rf.x + v2.x, v1_rf.y + v2.y);

        v3.x = Bouncey(v3.x, -1, 1);
        v3.y = Bouncey(v3.y, -1, 1);

        return v3;
    }

public float Bouncey(float number, float min, float max)
{
    float startingPosition = 0;
    float cycle = 2 * (max - min);
    float full_cycles = math.trunc(number / cycle);
    float modified_value = number-cycle*full_cycles;
    float position = startingPosition+modified_value;
    if (position < min) {
        position = min+(min-position);
        if (max < position) {
            return max - (position - max);
        }
        return position;
    }
    else if(min<= position && max >= position) {
        return position;
    }
    else {
        position = max - (position - max);
        if (position < min) {
            return min + (min - position);
        }
        return position;
    }

    // If the number is already within the range, return it
}
```

Comment: @DavidK I modified the post, and added a working algorithm for 2D. Now I just need to extend it to 3D

Comment: That is much clearer now. If the coordinates of $B$ can be $-1$ or $1$ when it is at a vertex then you have a cube of edge length $2$. Assuming Manhattan distance aligned with the axes of the cube, the center of a face is then $2$ units away from the nearest vertex (rather than $\sqrt2$ units away via Euclidean measure). I suppose when you say the reflection is on the same plane as $v_1$ and $v_2$, it implies $\operatorname{reflected}(v_1,v_2)$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$; the plane through the points $A$, $B$, and $C$ also passes through the center of the cube.

Comment: For $v_1=(0,0,1)$ and $v_2=(1,1,1)$, I calculate that $\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_2)=2$ but $\operatorname{distance}(v2,(1,1,0))=1$. I figure $\operatorname{reflected}(v_1,v_2)=(1,1,-1)$.

Comment: It is not generally true that $\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_2)=\operatorname{distance}(v_2,v_3)=2\times\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_3)$. First of all, if all three points are on one face, then $\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_3)=2\times\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_2)=2\times\operatorname{distance}(v_2,v_3)$. (You multiplied the wrong distance by $2$.) Also, if $v_1=-v_2$, then $v_3=v_1$ so the general rule is actually $\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_3)\leq2\times\operatorname{distance}(v_1,v_2)=2\times\operatorname{distance}(v_2,v_3)$.

Comment: If you agree with these recent comments then I think I finally understand what you're doing. It is an interesting question. The cases for $B$ at the center of an edge or face look simple enough, but $B$ at a vertex is a challenge.

Comment: Looks like I have to apologise for the miscalculated examples. You are right @DavidK, I intended to mean that d(v1,v2)=d(v2,v3)=1/2 * d(v1,v3), and yup, there are cases in which it is smaller, such as when v1=-v2 (although it might be the only case).
The above assumption of it being a linear combination is also correct.
The main motivation for this question is as follows: given a cubic direction A, and a cubic direction B to the next location, set the new intended direction at B to A reflected over B. This operation is, in 2d, akin to drawing a line along pixels (except we consider any dirs)

Answer (score 1):

### Definitions

In order to be able to discuss the constructions without using too many words, I will use the following definitions.
All vectors in these definitions are position vectors of points on the cube, whose center is at the origin.
The plane containing a vector is a plane through the origin parallel to the vector.

A *Manhattan path* is a path consisting only of straight segments on the surface of the cube parallel to one or another of the three axes.

A *minimal Manhattan path* between vectors $P$ and $Q$ is a Manhattan path between $P$ and $Q$ such that there is no shorter Manhattan path between $P$ and $Q$.

The *Manhattan distance* between vectors $P$ and $Q$, denoted $\mathrm{d_M}(P,Q)$, is the length of a minimal Manhattan path between $P$ and $Q$.

For two vectors $A$ and $B$, the *Manhattan reflection of $A$ across $B$* is a vector $C$ such that the plane that contains $A$ and $B$ also contains $C$ and such that
$\mathrm{d_M}(C,B) = \mathrm{d_M}(A,B)$.

### $B$ at the center of a face or edge

For $B$ at the center of a face (such as $B=(1,0,0)$)
or $B$ at the center of an edge (such as $B=(1,1,0)$),
given an arbitrary vector $A$ on the surface of the cube,
let $\gamma$ be a minimal Manhattan path between $A$ and $B$.

Now rotate the cube $180$ degrees around the vector $B$.
The image of the cube under this rotation is the cube itself.
The rotation takes $A$ to a vector $A'$ and takes $\gamma$ to a minimal Manhattan path $\gamma'$ between $A'$ and $B$. Moreover, the vector $A'$ is coplanar with the vectors $A$ and $B$.
Therefore $C = A'$ is the Manhattan reflection of $A$ across $B$.

These cases should be easy enough to code; the rotation around the center of a face reverses two coordinates and leaves the other coordinate unchanged,
while a rotation around the center of an edge reverses one coordinate
and swaps the other two coordinates.

### $B$ at a vertex

If $B$ is at a vertex, we must use a different method.

The Manhattan distance from $B$ to $-B$ (the opposite vertex) is $6$, since to build a Manhattan path from $B$ to $-B$ we have to travel a distance of at least $2$ units (not necessarily in contiguous segments) parallel to the $x$ axis, at least $2$ units parallel to the $y$ axis, and at least $2$ units parallel to the $z$ axis.
Moreover, if the Manhattan distance from $A$ to $B$ is $r$ and $C$ is the Manhattan reflection of $A$ across $B$, then the Manhattan distance from $A$ to $-B$ is $6-r$, the Manhattan distance from $C$ to $-B$ is $6-r$, and $C$ is coplanar with $A$ and $-B$;
therefore $C$ is the Manhattan reflection of $A$ across $-B$.

Therefore we can use $-B$ in place of $B$ in order to find $C$ if it is convenient for us to do so. That is, without loss of generality we can assume that $A$ is on one of the faces with a vertex at $B$, since every face has a vertex either at $B$ or $-B$.

Without loss of generality, we can also assume that $B = (1,1,1)$ and that
$A = (1, y_A, z_A)$ where $z_A \geq y_A$.
(If these assumptions initially are not true, we can make them true by reversing the direction of the axes as needed to make $B = (1,1,1)$, which means at least one of the coordinates of $A$ is $1$ due to the assumption that $A$ is on a face with vertex $B$; then permuting the labels of the axes so that the $x$ coordinate of $A$ is the coordinate with value $1$ and so that the $y$ coordinate of $A$ is less than the $z$ coordinate. At the end of the exercise we reverse these transformations to recover the correct coordinates of $C$.)

If we then have $A=B$, it follows that $C=B$ and we are done.
So we now just have to consider the case where $A \neq B$.

As a result of these assumptions, the plane containing $A$ and $B$ intersects an edge of the cube at $D = (1, -1, h)$ and intersects the opposite edge at $E = (-1, 1, -h)$,
where
$$ h = 1 - \frac{1 - z_A}{1 - y_A}. $$
(Note that the assumptions that $y_A \leq z_A$ and that $A \neq B$ imply that
$1 - y_A \neq 0$.)

We now consider two sub-cases.

In the first sub-case,
$$\mathrm{d_M}(A,B) = 2 - y_A - z_A \leq 3 + h = \mathrm{d_M}(E,B).$$
That is, $\mathrm{d_M}(C,B) = \mathrm{d_M}(A,B) \leq \mathrm{d_M}(E,B)$.
Therefore $C$ is on the line segment between $B$ and $E$ on the face $y=1$.
Let $C = (x_C, 1, z_C)$; then by similar right triangles on that face,
$$
\frac{1 - x_C}{2} = \frac{1 - z_C}{1 + h} = \frac{2 - y_A - z_A}{3 + h}.
$$
Solve for $x_C$ and $z_C$.

In the second sub-case,
$$\mathrm{d_M}(A,B) = 2 - y_A - z_A > 3 + h = \mathrm{d_M}(E,B).$$
This means that $C$ is on the line segment between $E$ and $-B$ (on the face $x=-1$),
that $\mathrm{d_M}(C,-B) = 6 - \mathrm{d_M}(A,B) = 4 + y_A + z_A$,
and that $\mathrm{d_M}(E,-B) = 3 - h$.
Let $C = (-1, y_C, z_C)$; then by similar right triangles,
$$
\frac{y_C + 1}{2} = \frac{z_C + 1}{1 - h} = \frac{4 + y_A + z_A}{3 - h}.
$$
Solve for $y_C$ and $z_C$.

I would probably follow this construction quite literally in coding.
The tricky part is to do the correct coordinate transformations to satisfy the assumptions and to remember what those transformations were so that they can be reversed. It might be useful to have code that allows you to conveniently create and multiply $3\times3$ matrices in order to keep track of the reverse transformation.